# Is it possible to create an image by using xml file

Tags: android, bitmap, touch, imageview

I am trying to create an image via xml file. I would like ask if it is possible to do so

The following is the code of XML file I want to create as an image in order to display in an imageview.

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
imageshow =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageshow);
items = fillMaps();

        SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,items,R.layout.spinner,
                new String[]{"name"},
                new int[]{R.id.title});

        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

        spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

Layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bible_help_title" />


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:layout_below="@id/bible_help_title">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:prompt="@string/bible_help_title"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageshow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_1"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

**After the user select a resource from Spinner, call showimagetask**

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int `arg2,long arg3) {`



                new showimagetask(arg2).execute(arg2);


                //if (!snoop.isRecycled()) { snoop.recycle();}

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
}
```

**showimagetask**

```
   public class showimagetask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> 
        {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int checkid;

    String Map_name;
    String Drawing_1;
    int resID;

     public showimagetask(int id) {
            checkid = id;

            HashMap map = (HashMap)items.get(id);
            Map_name= map.get("name").toString();
            Drawing_1= map.get("Drawing").toString();
            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(Drawing_1, "raw", "tool.mobile");  



        }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog =new ProgressDialog(BibleHelpActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle(Map_name);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();

        imageshow.setImageBitmap(null);
        snoop=null;
        System.gc();



    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        snoop= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(resID));
        //Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);

        return snoop;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        /*
        TouchImageView imageshow = imageButtonReference.get();
         */

        imageshow.setImageBitmap(snoop);
        imageshow.setTag(resID);
        dialog.dismiss();


     }

}


private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps()

{
    List<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String,String> i = new HashMap<String,String>();
        i.put("name","EricPhoto");
        i.put("Drawing", "img_101");
        items.add(i);
                    i = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    i.put("name","PeterPhoto");
            i.put("Drawing", "img_102");
            items.add(i);
        i = new HashMap<String,String>();
        i.put("name","Schedule");
        i.put("Drawing", "table_1");
        items.add(i);
return items;
    }
```

FIle in Raw Folder

```
img_101.jpg
img_102.jpg
table_1.xml
```

The code for table_1.xml in Raw Folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:background="@drawable/white"
             android:orientation="vertical" 
            >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10" />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Eric Graduation" /> 
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="17" />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="peter birthday" /> 
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your reasoning to do this is.

If all you aim to do is display some View structure as an image inside of an ImageView, there is an easier way to go about it.

Inflate your TableLayout as normal with the LayoutInflator. Once you have a reference to it you can call [getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) to get a bitmap object that can be passed to the ImageView.

```
Bitmap mImg = tbl.getDrawingCache();
mImgView.setImageBitmap(mImg);
```

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that I have a spinner for the users to select the resource from a list . Some of the resource are in image format and some of the resource are in table format[All resource are put in a raw folder]. Therefore, I want to convert the xml file into to an image in order to display it in an imageview.

Comment: I have update my code and given more explanation, may you have a look on it to see if it is more clear or not?

Comment: HI,Tim... do u have any advice for my question? Thankyou in advance